# "Hello World" guide/application for native Android application fetching Salesforce data?

Tags: mobile, documentation, android

I am well versed with both Android and Salesforce development separately, but this is my first time working on both platforms simultaneously.

### Is there any *Hello World* guide/application for creating a native Android application which simply fetches Salesforce data from one object?

For example, a native Android application which asks for Salesforce System Administrator credentials, and then displays all Account records from that environment.

I have a Salesforce Developer Environment, JDK 6, Android SDK, Eclipse linked with the Android SDK with ADT, Node.js, and Forcedroid.

The [sample mobile SDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/blob/master/doc/mobile_sdk.pdf?raw=true) guide provided by Salesforce talks more about configuration, than building a sample Hello World application.

I am looking for a guide or blog which explains how to set up a *Hello Word* application with screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link provides exactly what you need - a basic step by step tutorial to create a barebones Salesforce Android native app using Mobile SDK - http://www2.developerforce.com/mobile/getting-started/android

When you are ready to get beyond Hello World, I strongly recommend looking at the REST Explorer sample app that comes bundled with the SDK - https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/tree/master/native/SampleApps/RestExplorer

Answer (score 1):

See the following links. The second one is from SO. The first answers describes how you can use the Wsdl from Salesforce to connect using Java. You may have to modify it to work with Android.

http://hemhemanth.blogspot.com/2013/04/salesforce-mobile-sdk-for-android.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666525/salesforce-with-android